# setTimeout Reference Error in Pubnub Javascript SDK for Parse Cloud

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, pubnub, parse-server

I am trying register device with Parse Cloud code of PubNub
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/parse-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk

**[Error]: ReferenceError**: setTimeout is not defined

```
at Object.timeout (pubnub.js:2515:11)
at Object.PN_API (pubnub.js:2336:24)
at CREATE_PUBNUB (pubnub.js:244:24)
```

**//Cloud Code**

```
var PubNub = require('cloud/pubnub');
var pubnub = PubNub({
    publish_key: "pub-c-bd9ec61f-8783-4c62-8157-d214ab6f8eca",
    subscribe_key: "sub-c-065f58d8-ece5-11e5-baae-0619f8945a4f"
});
```

**//Error Thrown before calling registration**

```
pubnub.mobile_gw_provision ({
    device_id: identifier,
    op    : 'add',
    gw_type  : 'apns', // or 'gcm'
    channel  : 'my_chat',
    callback : mySuccessCallback,
    error   : myErrorCallback,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## setTimeout() is unavailable in  Parse.com platform SDK:

This may be a bug in current sdk, I have fixed by commenting setTimeout.

```
  //return setTimeout(fun, wait);
```

Comment: It was a refactoring/packaging regression. The above fixes it and we will roll out an updated SDK probably by tomorrow. Thanks for reporting.